# Mongoose remove all referenced objectID elements using pre or post hook

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have two schemas

**User Schema**

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
        first: { type: String, trim: true, required: true },
        last:  { type: String, trim: true, required: true }
  },
  department:{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref:'Department'},
  image:{ data: Buffer, contentType: String },
  phone: {type:String, required: true},
  email: {type: String, required: true, unique:true}
});
```

**Department Schema**

```
var DeparmentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
name:{ type: String, required: true },
date:{type:Date,default: Date.now},
employees:[{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref:'User'}] });
```

When a department gets deleted, all employees should also be deleted. I tried looping and deleting one by one. But it does not seem to the efficient way.

Can I remove all employee using mongoose pre or post hook in department schema?

Edit:
Failed to add department field in User Schema

Comment: Solved, Answer posted

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to do any looping.

Have you tried something like this?

```
var User = require(/* etc */);

DeparmentSchema.pre('remove', function (next) {
    console.log('deleting department', this);
    User.remove({ 
        _id: { $in: this.employees } // this.employees must be an array of ObjectIds
    }, function (err) {
        console.log(err);
        if (err) return next(err);
        next();
    });
});
```

Ensure also that you are using `.remove()` to trigger the hook.

Comment: A field got deleted while pasting the schema for user. User has a field called department that failed to add. The problem is Department is included in User, so if I requite User in department it's going to cause problem when running the code.

Comment: [`require` is always `require once`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8958113/1022914) - so there shouldn't be any problems using `require` again.

Comment: If you don't want to `require`, then you can replace `User.remove` with `this.model('User').remove` (as you have done in your answer).

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue using this pre hook

```
DepartmentSchema.pre('remove', function(next) {
    var self=this;
    this.employees.forEach(function(employee){
        self.model('User').remove({ _id: employee },function (err) {
            if(err){
                return next(err)
            }
        });
    });
    next();

 });
```

Comment: Be careful... `remove` is asynchronous whereas `forEach` is not. You should always wait till the asynchronous operation is completed before proceeding.