# NodeJS - How is logger object shared across project?

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging, module, project-structure

I have created a `logger` object in `utils/logger.js` using the `winston` package. The entry-point for my project is `index.js` where I have `const logger = require('./utils/logger')`. How do I 'cascade' this logger object across *all* of project files (~20)? Should each file in my project also do a `const logger = require('../utils/logger)` ? If so, aren't they all individual `logger` objects when I do a `node index.js`?

I am using the following (from [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-winston-to-log-node-js-applications)) for `utils.logger.js`.

```js
var appRoot = require('app-root-path');
var winston = require('winston');

// define the custom settings for each transport (file, console)
var options = {
  file: {
    level: 'info',
    filename: `${appRoot}/logs/app.log`,
    handleExceptions: true,
    json: true,
    maxsize: 5242880, // 5MB
    maxFiles: 5,
    colorize: false,
  },
  console: {
    level: 'debug',
    handleExceptions: true,
    json: false,
    colorize: true,
  },
};

// instantiate a new Winston Logger with the settings defined above
var logger = new winston.Logger({
  transports: [
    new winston.transports.File(options.file),
    new winston.transports.Console(options.console)
  ],
  exitOnError: false, // do not exit on handled exceptions
});

// create a stream object with a 'write' function that will be used by `morgan`
logger.stream = {
  write: function(message, encoding) {
    // use the 'info' log level so the output will be picked up by both transports (file and console)
    logger.info(message);
  },
};

module.exports = logger;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, what you can do is create a function in the same file for logging and export those functions in your file, this way you'll be using the same object all over your project.

```
utils/logger.js



function InfoLogger(message){
logger.info(message);
}

module.exports = {InfoLogger}
```

**Update:**
From the answer over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8958097/is-there-a-way-to-require-a-js-file-only-once-in-nodejs) I learned that nodejs always uses 'require once' approach.

> `After` you call require the first time, require uses a cache and will
> always return the same object.

I also tried this in the test project where I used console.log in the start of file and exported a function from the file. Then imported the function multiple times in my project and the console.log only ran once.

So your `var logger =` will only run once and you're sharing the same object

Comment: However, upon `require('../utils/logger.js')`, the `var logger =` is executed. This means, the `logger` object is created every time. How do I create the `logger` object only once and share across the project?

Comment: Not exactly, because require only instantiates once the exported variable is shared among all "requiring" functions. Just ran a test for myself with a log to check if the logger.js create is run twice,and it only ran once, as expected :)